# Independence of choice of represepresentatives, Filter,Reduced product

Tags: set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, filters, binary-operations

[Here](http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/onderwijs/set_theory/Jech/12-models_of_set_theory.pdf), on page 158, how do I see that (12.4) and (12.5)
does not depend on the choice of representatives from the equivalence classes
$[f_1],...,[f_n]$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to verify that and said verification is a bit tedious - but essentially trivial.

It all comes down to two things:

1. The definition of $f =_{F} g$ and
2. the fact that $F$ is a filter.

Using those, the proof boils down to intersecting finitely many sets - each of which are in the filter - to see that a certain superset of this intersection ends up in the filter and witnesses that in fact our interpretation of predicates and functions is independent of our choice of representatives.

I'll leave the mechanical verification of this fact to you - it's a useful exercise which, while tedious and a bit boring, should help you get more comfortable with reduced products and the way their elements are formed.

Comment: I don't think that it's very likely for you to get stuck but if you do, feel free to let me know and I'll demonstrate the proof with an exemplary case.

Comment: I would like if you could write down some example, say (12.5)...

Comment: @user122424 You should try it yourself first and - to make the notation easier just assume that $n = 1$. Show where you got stuck (if you do, which I doubt) and then I'll help you to get unstuck. This is really one of those proofs where you can't go wrong - you just have to write down the obvious thing and realize that it works.

Comment: I do not even know how to start.

Comment: @user122424 Suppose $f =_{F} g$ and $F^{\mathfrak{U}}([f]) = [h]$. This means that $\{x \in S \mid f \ldots \} \in F$ and $\{ x \in S \mid h \ldots \} \in F$. But then their intersection is in $F$ and the set witnessing that $F^{\mathfrak{U}}([g]) = [h]$ is a superset of that set and thus also in $F$...

Comment: It's a bit confusing that $F$ denotes both a function symbol and the filter - but that's Jech's fault. I simply adopted his notation.